# Authenticate people online with simple public / private key scheme or similar

Tags: authentication, public-key-infrastructure, rsa, public-key

how can I ensure that person X on website A is the same person who contacts me?
Here is my use case.

On website A I post message asking username X to contact me. Someone send me an email - how do I ensure it is the same person? Website A does not have a private messaging functionality and all posts are public and visible for everyone.

I was thinking about most obvious way to do it when username X posts his public key and then I encrypt code word with it and send him, but it requires knowledge of public/private keys, the keys themselves and the keys are really long usually.

Is there an easier way to authenticate people, maybe some website where you can use short words as public / private key or something like that? There is a lot of webservices where you can generate RSA keys and do all (d)encryption stuff, but as I've said it will not work for me.

Comment: Can you just reply to the email and ask the sender to post something specific on the web site as user X?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you trust that website and how they authenticate that user, you could ask the user to create a PGP key and share through that website their public key.

They can then use digital signature to prove their identity.

An alternative way, if you do not want the user to have to deal with public/private keys would be to ask on that forum what their email address is, and to check that the domain has implemented SPF, DKIM, and DMARC. Depending on your threat model, this could provide enough assurance that this is the right contact.

Comment: Thanks, but as I've said it will require for user to learn how to use public / private keys and then store these keys somewhere. I am looking for some webservice which will allow me to enter code word, then public and private password, so in essence same thing but with shorter / simpler to use private/public keys.

Comment: I added an alternative solution not relying directly on encryption, but on email security mechanisms. (DKIM do rely on encryption however.)

Comment: so they will have email address on gmail, how will that help me ensure that person who contacts me is the same?

Comment: let's have an example - here is my email address, email@example.com. Now how do you prove me in email that email sender is Yuriko from stackexchange?

Comment: User_X posts their email address and send an email to yours. You can check that the "From" is indeed User_X, and check that the domain has implemented SPF, DKIM, and DMARC. For example using [MXToolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/).

Comment: You are trolling or really do not understand the question :) I create gmail address and write in name - Yuriko. Gmail has  SPF, DKIM, and DMARC - but it does not prove in any way that Yuriko from Gmail is Yuriko from Stackexchange.

Comment: I invite you to read again the first five words.